# Weierstrass $\wp$-Function Addition Property

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, riemann-surfaces, elliptic-functions

Consider the function

$$
\det\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
&1 &\wp(z) &\wp'(z) \\
&1 &\wp(w) &\wp'(w) \\
&1 &\wp(-z-w) &\wp'(-z-w) \end{array} \right)=f(z)
$$

I'm trying to prove that it has at least $6$ distinct zeroes if $w\notin\frac{1}{3}\Lambda$ and at least $5$ zeroes with multiplicity otherwise. Then by a degree argument $f$ is obviously identically zero. I've got no idea how to show this though! Obviously $f$ has a zero at $z=w$. Apart from that I know the zeroes of $\wp'$ but they seem to be of no help. It seems like I'm meant to try $z=3w$ but this doesn't work! A hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See here for a nice outline: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/121662/5363

Comment: I've read that and don't really understand it at all! I think that this question is meant to be solved much more simply, since we haven't really talked about any of the theory in the course.

Comment: You could simply use the expansions and verify that the principal part vanishes, then apply Liouville (note that $f$ is $\Lambda$-periodic by definition). This makes a straightforward if somewhat messy calculation.

Comment: Maybe I'm being stupid but I don't see how that tells me how many zeroes I have!

Comment: Okay have found two more, namely $z=-2w$, $z=-\frac{1}{2}w$ but these put different constraints on $w$ to the ones I've been given!

Comment: I was simply suggesting alternative approaches. That's all...

Comment: Just to clarify the point of this question... I'm trying to prove that there are these zeroes, without resorting to proving that $f$ is identically zero first!

Comment: Yeah I see, thank you :). I agree that is probably a better way of showing it, but it's not really how I need to prove it! (I've put up a clarifying comment to that effect)